# i want to join these two vertical lines with my custom cursor starting and ending which is a line(horizontal)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
      perspective: 500px;
      perspective-origin: top;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: black;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .cursor {
      position: absolute;
      width: 8rem;
      height: 3px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: white;
      z-index: 11;
      left: -50px;
      top: 30px;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: translateZ(100px) rotateX(-0deg);
    }
    
    .follow_cursor {
      position: absolute;
      background: white;
      width: 2px;
      height: 5rem;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0%;
      right: 0;
      transform-origin: top;
      backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    }
    
    .follow_cursor2 {
      position: absolute;
      background: white;
      width: 2px;
      height: 2rem;
      z-index: 3;
      top: 100%;
      left: 100%;
      right: 0px;
      transform-origin: top;
      backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- this div need to be fixed -->
  <div class="follow_cursor"></div>
  <div class="follow_cursor2"></div>
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</body>
<script>
  let cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
  let main = document.querySelector(".main");
  const follow = document.querySelector(".follow_cursor");
  const follow_2 = document.querySelector(".follow_cursor2");

  const origR = follow.getBoundingClientRect();
  const origR_2 = follow_2.getBoundingClientRect();

  document.onmousemove = (e) => {
    let x = e.pageX;
    let y = e.pageY;

    cursor.style.transform = `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px , 0)`;
    // calculate distance and angle.

    let xf = origR.left + origR.width / 2;
    let x2f = origR_2.left + origR_2.width / 2;

    let yf = origR.top;
    let y2f = origR_2.top;
    // // distance to cursor from follow
    let dist = Math.sqrt((xf - x) * (xf - x) + (yf - y) * (yf - y));
    let dist2 = Math.sqrt((x2f - x) * (x2f - x) + (y2f - y) * (y2f - y));

    // console.log(dist)
    var angle = 0;
    var angle2 = 0;
    // get the rotation angle
    angle = 90 + (Math.atan2(yf - y, xf - x) * 180) / Math.PI;
    angle2 = 90 + (Math.atan2(y2f - y, x2f - x) * 180) / Math.PI;

    follow.style.transform =
      "rotateZ(" + angle + "deg) scaleY(" + dist / origR.height + ")";

    follow_2.style.transform =
      "rotateZ(" + angle2 + "deg) scaleY(" + dist2 / origR_2.height + ")";
  };
</script>

</html>
```

> i am trying to join the vertical lines with my custom cursor but its not working.
> i need to join these cursor ending with these vertical line endings.
> the link of this image given below
> you can run the snippets and check the image to take the refrence what i am trying to do.
> i will be thankful if you will help me.
> my communication skill are not good hope you will understand

[i want this lines to look like this in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRahs.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear. In order to receive help, plese improve it.

Comment: Please run the snippet and check the image..

Comment: The code is hard to read, try to make your variable more descriptive and add some explanations..

Comment: @Rahul You mean that you want something like that ? http://prntscr.com/1w41yhe

Comment: Yes exactly, you should try.

Comment: There are no vertical lines in your image so I am not at all clear what you are wanting to do as your requirement mentions joining vertical lines. Could you explain some more? Thanks.

Comment: @AHaworth the question has been solved. checkout the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was hard to read, but I think the `transform: translateZ()` in the initial css had to do with the error.

I've made you a working example containing 3 elements: the lines and the custom cursor.

I calculate the window height (`win_H`) and width (`win_W`) and the width of the custom cursor (`myc_W`).

The lines are fixed at the *left and right bottom* of the window, touching at the left and right corner of the custom pointer. From there it's simply maths: calculate the triangles (Pythagoras c2=a2+b2) and the angles (note the angles are in radials, not degrees!).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Document</title>
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 500px;
  perspective-origin: top;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}
#my_cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: white;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
#line_1{
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}
#line_2{
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="line_1"></div>
<div id="line_2"></div>
<div id="my_cursor"></div>
</body>

<script>
let 
my_cursor = document.getElementById("my_cursor"),
line_1 = document.getElementById("line_1"),
line_2 = document.getElementById("line_2"),

win_W=window.innerWidth,
win_H=window.innerHeight,
myc_W=(my_cursor.getBoundingClientRect().width)/2
;

//SET STARTING POSITION in middle of screen
_calculate( (win_W/2), (win_H/2));


document.onmousemove = (e) => {
_calculate( e.pageX, e.pageY);
}

function _calculate(mouseX,mouseY){
//CUSTOM CURSOR position:
let myc_XL = mouseX - myc_W,
      myc_XR = mouseX + myc_W,
      myc_Y = mouseY;
my_cursor.style.transform = `translate3d(${myc_XL}px, ${myc_Y}px , 0)`;

let a,b,c,angle;

//LINE 1
a = myc_XL;
b = win_H - mouseY;
c = Math.sqrt((a*a)+(b*b));
angle = Math.asin(  a /c );
line_1.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + angle + "rad) scaleY(" + (c/win_H) + ")";

//LINE 2
a = win_W - myc_XR;
c = Math.sqrt((a*a)+(b*b));
angle = Math.asin( a / c );
line_2.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + (-angle) + "rad) scaleY(" + (c/win_H) + ")";
};
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: infinite thanks, you solved my problem..

Comment: You're welcome. It was fun.

Comment: @Michel well done

Comment: @Rahul Just for fun: if you want to hide the default mousepointer of the browser you can use `document.body.style.cursor = 'none';`. Then you end up with only your custom corsor. And if the answer satisfies you, please accept it so the question can be closed.

Comment: @Michel I have accepted your question and thanks again for your valuable time in solving this question.